# JRuby on Rails: issue date parse issue for stylesheet_link_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jruby, sprockets, jrubyonrails

I am developing a project using Rails on jRuby. All were good until a strange issue triggers an internal server error. It's strange that in some occasions it loads perfectly, although there's no change in code anywhere.

It originates from the line:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all' %>
```

and the error is:

```
undefined method `_parse' for Java::JavaUtil::Date:Class
```

The top few line of the stack trace looks like:

```
<home_dir>/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.10/lib/ruby/1.9/time.rb:265:in `parse'
sprockets (2.11.0) lib/sprockets/processed_asset.rb:79:in `initialize'
sprockets (2.11.0) lib/sprockets/processed_asset.rb:47:in `init_with'
org/jruby/RubyArray.java:2409:in `map'
sprockets (2.11.0) lib/sprockets/processed_asset.rb:46:in `init_with'
sprockets (2.11.0) lib/sprockets/asset.rb:24:in `from_hash'
sprockets (2.11.0) lib/sprockets/caching.rb:54:in `cache_asset'
sprockets (2.11.0) lib/sprockets/index.rb:93:in `build_asset'
sprockets (2.11.0) lib/sprockets/base.rb:287:in `find_asset'
sprockets (2.11.0) lib/sprockets/index.rb:61:in `find_asset'
...
```

As a general trouble shooting I've tried removing all the latest stylesheet and javascript files. Disabled `turbolinks` but the problem persists.

Had anybody encountered this issue? Any suggestions how to overcome, or even how to bypass this issue?

Rails version: 4.1.4
jRuby version: jruby 1.7.10 (1.9.3p392)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you very likey have a `import java.util.Date` or similar `java_import Java::JavaUtil::Date` somewhere along your code which replaces the Ruby `Date` constant with another one ...

Comment: This was the issue. Actually I too found this and corrected. I did not look in this page after not getting an answer in first few hrs. 

But you deserve full credit for guessing it correctly. Thank you.